# Recording the time it takes to process a form

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a form that has a submission button on it. Is it possible to record the time that the submit button is pressed and then, once the form has run, display how long it took to process on the page?

Comment: Just save the timestamp at the beginning of the submission handler, and then at the end of the submission handler. Once you have those values, you know how much it took to the submission handler to handle the form. Is there anything specific that you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

I use [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) to monitor load times:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/05/14/using-httpwatch-to-measure-page-load-times-for-new-and-existing-users/

You should be able to get the numbers you want with the free version.